# Firefox javascript debugger and breakpoints - why doesn't console respond?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

When debugging javascript in the Firefox (latest/Windows 10x64) console, sometimes when I set a breakpoint and execution stops there, the console doesn't respond with any output.  For example, I can type any function or variable name into the console but when I hit Enter, it simply echoes my input but nothing happens.

It's as if the console interpreter is paused along with the code being debugged, and any input is ignored.

However, this only happens sometimes, and I haven't figured out a pattern yet.  Any clues? it's super annoying when you are trying to echo the value of a variable or execute something before stepping to the next line.

Chrome always works fine for the same breakpoint location.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to output global variable? , I had before and only global variables, functions that works.. that if i understand your question correctly.

Comment: It doesn't matter what I try to output, nothing happens except that it echoes the text I type in.  It won't raise any errors even if I type syntactically incorrect text.  it simply echoes the text.

Comment: I can type something like "window" (without the quotes) and where it should show the 'window' object, it simply echoes the word "window" in the console.

Comment: Also this has happened on other Windows versions and other Firefox versions.  I can always depend on Chrome to work in these situations so I usually end up switching to Chrome to debug when I run into this.  I was just wondering if I'm doing something wrong which causes it?  And as I said, most of the time it works fine.

Comment: will you show the screenshot of your console, is the log menu of console selected.

Comment: Screenshot added to the question. You can see that I'm even typing invalid stuff and not getting any response.  No errors etc. Just echoing the text I enter.

Comment: It's quite maddening as I'm in the middle of debugging then have to switch browsers.  I must be doing something wrong but I sure can't see it!